# tkinter photo image error: pyimage1 doesnt exist

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
class main(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    tk.Tk.geometry(self, "600x600")
    tk.Tk.configure(self, bg='green')
    container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.frames = {}

    for F in ([Login_Page, customer_menu, takeoutbook, return_book, admin_menu, add_user, add_book]):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.show_frame(admin_menu
                    )

def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

class showbutton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, label, **kw):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master=master, **kw)
        self.label = label
        self.defaultBackground = self['bg']
        self.bind('<Enter>', self.enter)
        self.bind('<Leave>', self.leave)

    def enter(self, e):
        self.label.configure(show='')
        self['background'] = self['activebackground']
        self['cursor'] = 'trek'


    def leave(self, e):
        self.label.configure(show='*')
        self['background'] = self.defaultBackground
        self['cursor'] = 'arrow'

class add_user(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    img = PhotoImage(filr = 'image.gif')
    passwordrntry = tk.Entry(self , font = 'calibri 15').place(x = 10 , y = 10)
    button = showbutton(self , passwordentry , font = 'calibri 16' , image = img1)
    button.place(x = 20 , y = 20)
```

the image doesn't show up on the button whenever the frame is raise and whenever i hover over the button and then leave the button i get the error. whenever i comment out the self['background'] and self[cursor] part of the showbutton class the error no longer shows up but the image still doesn't appear on the button

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Python\Obrien's library\library.py", line 323, in leave
    self['background'] = self.defaultBackground
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1492, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1485, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

Comment: It is because the image is destroyed when `__init__()` of `add_user` class completed.  Try changing `img = PhotoImage(...)` to `self.img = PhotoImage(...)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)